# 'mat-slide-toggle' is not a known element after import

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, slidetoggle

I'm trying to use `<mat-slide-toggle>Click me!</mat-slide-toggle>`inside a component which already has `MatSlideToggleModule` imported, but I'm still getting the message that it's not a known element.

*Angular version: 8.0.1*

**HTML Page (slide-page.html)**

```
<div class="grid-slide-toggle-material"> 
  <mat-slide-toggle>Click me!</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

**Module (slide-page.module.ts)**

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core'; 
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule } from 'projects/authenticator/src/shared/modules/material.module';
import { BasicModule } from 'src/app/shared/modules/basic/basic.module';
import { MatButtonToggleModule, MatButtonToggleGroup } from '@angular/material';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule 
  ]
})
export class SlidePageModule { }
```

How is it possible that the html is not being recognized even after the imports in the item's module?

Comment: I got this error and then I noticed that my component was somehow declared in app.module although it was supposed to be in sub-module called `admin`. No idea how it got there. Fixing the declarations solved the issue

Comment: consider selecting accepted answer @MattDAVM

Answer (score 14):

As Daniel suggested,
you need to add MatSlideToggleModule to your missing export in @NgModule.

**But**, please mind to write `MatSlideToggleModule` instead of `MatSlideToogleModule`.

In app.moudle.ts, add:

```
`import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle'`
```

inside @NgModule, imports, add:

```
MatSlideToggleModule
```

Answer (score 3):

try to add MatSlideToogleModule to your missing export in @NgModule.

Adding one more idea. Where do you have declared a component? Assume that your component is calling slidePageComponent.

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core'; 
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule } from 'projects/authenticator/src/shared/modules/material.module';
import { BasicModule } from 'src/app/shared/modules/basic/basic.module';
import { MatButtonToggleModule, MatButtonToggleGroup } from '@angular/material';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SlidePageComponent } from './component/slide-page.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  SlidePageComponent
],
  imports: [
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule 
  ],
exports: [
    MatSlideToggleModule 
]
})
export class SlidePageModule { }
```

Comment: Tried it out, still receiving "is not a known element"

Comment: I edit my example. Look for declarations - you missing in declaration import of your slide-page-component.ts

Its just example your file path can be different. 
Let me know if this helps you.